# Как одним #define запретить вывод в консоль в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Существует ли какой-то `#define` для запрета вывода текста в консоль? Например, такого:

```
qDebug() << "ololo";
```

Почему-то текст выводится даже в релизной сборке.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В файл проекта надо добавить строку

```
DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
```